# Error returned executing composite API from Postman

Tags: api, integration, postman, composite

I am using POstman to execute composite API. Got the sample request from this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm

Here is my postman setup:
[image]

URL I am hitting is composite API, version is V59. All endpoint,authentication,access tokens looks good because I was able to use Bulk API before using composite API.

Response I received:

```
{
    "compositeResponse": [
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
                    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 404,
            "referenceId": "NewAccount"
        },
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "The transaction was rolled back since another operation in the same transaction failed."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "NewAccountInfo"
        },
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "The transaction was rolled back since another operation in the same transaction failed."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "NewContact"
        },
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "The transaction was rolled back since another operation in the same transaction failed."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "NewAccountOwner"
        },
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "The transaction was rolled back since another operation in the same transaction failed."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "AccountMetadata"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is that I am missing? Please assist.

Comment: v60.0? Are you doing this in a sandbox that's been updated to Spring '24?

Comment: All orgs are on Spring '24 since this Monday so API v60.0 is correct.

Comment: @SfdcBat can you check that you have proper permissions to create an account using the REST > SObjects > SObject Create request from the Postman collection?

Comment: Ah Yes, it is in v60. And also I do have access to objects.

Comment: I am not sure why it would not work with 59, is it not back compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Version of composite API from 59.0 to 60.0 that fixed the issue. But I am not sure why it would not work with 59!

Comment: Wait, so you were using `/composite/v59.0` for the overall request but then using `/v60.0/sobjects/Account` in the subrequest? If that's the case, why would you think that using a more recent api version (compared to the overall request) would work?

Comment: What i did was instead of using /composite/v59.0 I used - /composite/v60.0

Comment: Yeah, I can see that because that's what you wrote. My comment was _why did you think having a newer api version in the subrequests would work_? As usual, being detailed really is important on sites like this.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to understand why would changing it to v60.0 would make this work. i'm not sure

Comment: We're either talking past each other, or maybe there's just a breakdown in understanding somewhere. What I've been saying this whole time is _because the API version of the overall composite request apparently needs to be less than or equal to the API version used in the subrequests_. Why would the v59.0 API know anything about the API versions that are newer than it? That would be _forward compatibility_ (which can happen, but is less common). If you were to try v58.0 in the composite and v59.0 in the subrequests, I'd expect it should also error out.

Comment: I assume you are thinking composite and subrequests are on two different API version, If so its not. There is only one API uri that I have to for all request( including subrequests) which is /services/data/v60.0/composite/ . So only 1 URI.

Comment: That version mismatch is _literally the entire reason for your question_. You did have that mismatch.